# Is a HoloLens emulator bluetooth passthrough available?

Tags: uwp, hololens, hololens-emulator

Is it possible to connect an external bluetooth device to the HoloLens emulator?

Than it seems that in the HoloLens Emulator settings the device options are missing which in the real HoloLens seems to exist.

Do somebody have experiance with connecting a device to the emulator?

Best regards
Kaffi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can connect external Bluetooth devices to the HoloLens.  In the actual device there is a Bluetooth page in the settings screen.

The Bluetooth screen is missing from the settings in the emulator, and Bluetooth devices are not supported in the current release of the emulator.